# Paginating Result Array Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Make pagination for my result array from Simple Parser DOM and i no have any idea was my code below writed properly or have missed something.

**Controller/Result_c.php**: here is the code how to get my result and save it on `$result`, if i get 12 result from that, i want to display them with pagination.

```
$data['links'] = array(
'https://www.suara.com/bisnis/bisnis-category/keuangan',
'https://market.bisnis.com',
'https://www.cnbcindonesia.com/investment',
'https://finance.detik.com/market-research?tag_from=wp_finance_secondnav_Market%20Research'
);

$data['inputcari'] = $this->input->post('inputcari');
$data['terms'] = explode(' ', $data['inputcari']);
foreach ($data['terms'] as $term) {
foreach ($data['links'] as $link) {
$html = file_get_html($link);
foreach ($html->find('div[class="item-content item-right"], div[class="col-custom left"]') as $konten) {
foreach ($konten->find('h4,h2') as $tags) {
foreach ($tags->find('a') as $urls) {
foreach ($konten->find('p,div[class="description"]') as $desc) {
if (stripos($tags->plaintext, $term) !== false) {
$row['judul'] = $tags->plaintext;
$row['desc'] = $desc->plaintext;
$row['url'] = $urls->href;
$result[] = $row;
}
break;
}}}}}}
```

**Controller/Result_c.php**: Next code giving pagination config:

```
 $config = array();
 $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "result_c";
 $config["total_rows"] = count($result);
 $config["per_page"] = 5;
 $config["uri_segment"] = 2;

 $this->pagination->initialize($config);

 $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

 $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
 $this->$data['res'] = $this->$result->fetch_row($config["per_page"], $page);
   
 $data['title'] = "Beranda";
 $this->load->view('tamplate/users/header_u', $data);
 $this->load->view('result', $data);
 $this->load->view('tamplate/users/footer_u');
```

**View/result.php**: My Views to display them.

```
 <?php
 Foreach ($res as $r) : ?>
 <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap cardcontent">
 <div class="col-6 itemcard">
 <div class="itemberita">
 <ul>
 <li>
 <b><?php echo $r['judul']; ?></b>
 <p><?php echo $r['desc']; ?></p>
 <div class="litinfo">
 <p><small><?php echo parse_url($r['url'], PHP_URL_HOST);?></small></p>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <a href="<?php echo $r['url']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnlanjut"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So what i have missed?